# Testdisk can't/won't recognise hard disk

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery, fdisk, testdisk

After moving a number of hard drives from an Ubuntu desktop to dedicated Ubuntu server, I'm finding it hard to get Ubuntu server to recognise one of the drives. It's a 4tb WD green which was formatted using a GPT table and as ext4 less than 8 months ago, but now, it seems like it's lost.

`sudo blkid` and `sudo fdisk -l` both yield nothing more than a list of existing, working drives - the problematic drive is definitely not listed.

I've tried putting the drive in a SATA connected hot swap trayless drive alongside the others and it doesn't show up whatsoever, under any command.

However, running `ls /dev/ | grep sd` before attaching the drive in an external USB caddy, gives me all disks, but running it after shows an extra disk `/dev/sdg`, but with no partition (ie. there is no `/dev/sdg1`). Trying to mount the disk reports `bad superblock`, or words to that effect.

So I looked to Tesdisk to help me out, but when I run `sudo testdisk`, it fails to show the USB attached disk (`/dev/sdg`), it shows all the other disks available to me. I've used testdisk before and got great results, but it doesn't seem to like this scenario. Am I doing something wrong?

I've searched for days now for a solution and this is my last resort, is there anything I can do or should I reluctantly give up on the drive? I'm relatively new to all this and determined not to lose it if I can help it, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: If this drive is sdg then it would show up in both `blkid` and `fdisk -l`.  What do you have in /proc/partitions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use the original disk any more!
2. Make a copy of the drive using `ddrescue` on an identical (or larger) disk

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gddrescue
   sudo ddrescue --binary-prefixes --cluster-size=64 --sparse --timeout=20s /dev/sdg /dev/sdX /path/to/file.log
   ```

   where `/dev/sdg` is your disk when you can read the disk, but not its partition table and `X` is the drive letter for the extra disk...
3. Try the duplicate!

   If the duplicate doesn't work either, try recovering the secondary
   copy of the GPT:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gdisk
   sudo gdisk /dev/sdg
   ```

   You will then get this:

   ```
   Command (? for help):
   ```

   Type `r`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

   You will then get this:

   ```
   recovery/transformation command (? for help):
   ```

   Type `b`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. For the future: [back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) before moving drives!

[<sub>Partly sourced from here...</sub>](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)